# Eight Queens - Diagonal Movement

Tags: java, algorithm, n-queens

I have an 8 by 8 chess board that I am trying to implement the eight queen puzzle. In my game I have made a function that checks for the movement of queens and once a button gets pressed in my board, all rows and columns that a specific queen could move to get turned off so that no two queens are attacking each other. I am stuck however trying to figure out how I could get all diagonal buttons to get turned off as well in my code.

```
private JButton[][] Squares = new JButton[8][8];
for (int i = 0; i < Squares.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Squares[i].length; j++) {
                    if(Squares[i][j].getModel().isPressed()){
                    for (int x=0; x<8; x++){
                        Squares[i][x].setEnabled(false); //turns off column buttons
                        Squares[x][j].setEnabled(false); //turns off row buttons
                        //Squares[i][j+1].setEnabled(false);
                        //Squares[i+1][j-1].setEnabled(false);


        }
```

What do I need to do in order to disable all diagonal buttons once a queen gets placed on the chessboard?

EDIT: I noticed that if I do `Squares[x][x].setEnabled(false);` then it will give me one of the two diagonals, however this only gives the diagonal one time and after clicking on a second button everything breaks.

Comment: What do you notice about the co-ordinates of the squares on the main diagonal?  What about the co-ords of the squares on the diagonal above that?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, I've been running into errors no matter what I try and am finally at the point where I'm stuck. I know that if I try incrementing by one I can sometimes get one diagonal but since I am hardcoding whenever I attempt that, if I am on the last column/row I can often run into errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start out from `[i][j]`, and keep advancing (using your loop var `x`) on both rows an columns in parallel. The only tricky part is how to avoid falling off the edge of the board. Note that unlike the rows/columns, your diagonal won't necessarily have 8 squares

one way to do this, using the same basic loop over `x`, is -

```
if (i+x < Squares.length && j+x < Squares[i].length)
    Squares[i+x][j+x].setEnabled(false);             
if (i-x >= 0 && j-x >= 0)
    Squares[i-x][j-x].setEnabled(false);             
if (i-x >= 0 && j+x < Squares[i].length)
    Squares[i-x][j+x].setEnabled(false);             
if (i+x < Squares.length && j-x >=0)
    Squares[i+x][j-x].setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently answered a similar question on SO.

You can check out my code in response to [the similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74610912/18781246).

But basically, if your Queen's position is `[a][b]`.
And you'd like to check if another position's coordinates `[x][y]` are on the diagonal.

- `y-x == b-a` if the cells are on the same right diagonal.
- `x+y == a+b` if your cells are on the same left diagonal.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question. If you are looking for a way to select all diagonal cells when a queen is places then it is known that those cells would occur in `|i-j|` (i.e. the absolute value). Here is a code where whenever `Squares[indx1,indx2]` is pressed, will do something with the diagonal cells... Does that make sense?

```
public static void pressed(int indx1,int indx2){
    // Squares[indx1][indx2] is pressed
    // Assign 1 to diagonal cells 
    for(int i=0;i<Squares.length;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<Squares.length;j++)
        if(Math.abs(indx1-i)==Math.abs(indx2-j))
            Squares[i][j]=1;
}
```